# SwiftUIでPHPickerViewControllerから取ってきた(特定の)動画のサムネイルが取得できない

Tags: swift, swiftui, uikit

UIKitのPHPickerViewControllerをUIViewControllerRepresentableでSwiftUIで使えるようにして、写真アプリから動画を取ってきて、１フレームを画像(サムネイル)として`AVAssetImageGenerator`で取得して表示しようとしているのですが、一部の動画がうまくいきません。

画面を録画したような動画は全てうまくいきません。

#### エラー内容

```
Error Domain=AVFoundationErrorDomain Code=-11829 "Cannot Open" UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=This media may be damaged., NSLocalizedDescription=Cannot Open, NSUnderlyingError=0x28233e970 {Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-12848 "(null)"}}
```

#### ファイル先

```
/private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/E28C8686-3039-426C-9EB0-97237DC4D785/tmp/version=1&uuid=4231FFD7-0969-417C-8A9A-07062D463E40&mode=compatible.mp4
```

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
  @State var results: [PHPickerResult] = []
  @State var isPresentedPhotoPicker = false
  @State var images: [NSItemProviderReading] = []
  @State var tappedVideoURL: URL?
  
  private func loadPhoto(from provider: NSItemProvider) async throws -> NSItemProviderReading? {
    if provider.canLoadObject(ofClass: PHLivePhoto.self) {
      return try await provider.loadObject(ofClass: PHLivePhoto.self)
    }
    
    else if provider.canLoadObject(ofClass: UIImage.self) {
      return try await provider.loadObject(ofClass: UIImage.self)
    }
    
    else if provider.hasItemConformingToTypeIdentifier(UTType.movie.identifier) {
      let secureCoding = try await provider.loadItem(forTypeIdentifier: UTType.movie.identifier, options: nil)
      
      if let url = secureCoding as? URL {
        let localURL = FileManager.default.temporaryDirectory.appendingPathComponent(url.lastPathComponent)
        
        try? FileManager.default.removeItem(at: localURL)
        try FileManager.default.copyItem(at: url, to: localURL)
        
        return localURL as NSItemProviderReading
      }
    }
    
    return nil
  }
  
  private func loadPhotos(results: [PHPickerResult]) async throws -> [NSItemProviderReading] {
    var images: [NSItemProviderReading?] = []
    
    try await withThrowingTaskGroup(of: Optional<NSItemProviderReading>.self) { group in
      for provider in results.map(\.itemProvider) {
        group.addTask {
          return try await loadPhoto(from: provider)
        }
      }
      
      for try await data in group {
        images.append(data)
      }
    }
    
    return images.compactMap { $0 }
  }
  
  func getThumbnailImage(url: URL) -> UIImage? {
    let asset: AVAsset = .init(url: url)
    let generator = AVAssetImageGenerator(asset: asset)
    do {
      let cgImage = try generator.copyCGImage(at: asset.duration, actualTime: nil)
      let uiImage: UIImage = .init(cgImage: cgImage)
      return uiImage
    } catch {
      print(error)
      return nil
    }
  }
  
  var body: some View {
    VStack {
      Button(action: {
        isPresentedPhotoPicker.toggle()
      }, label: {
        Image(systemName: "photo")
      })
      .sheet(isPresented: $isPresentedPhotoPicker) {
        PhotoPicker(results: $results)
      }
      
      ScrollView(.horizontal) {
        HStack {
          ForEach(0..<images.count, id: \.self) { index in
            if let livePhoto = images[index] as? PHLivePhoto {
              LivePhoto(livePhoto: livePhoto)
                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                .frame(maxWidth: 240)
            }
            else if let uiimage = images[index] as? UIImage {
              Image(uiImage: uiimage)
                .resizable()
                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                .frame(height: 240)
            } else if let url = images[index] as? URL {
              ZStack {
                if let uiImage = getThumbnailImage(url: url) {
                  Image(uiImage: uiImage)
                    .resizable()
                    .frame(maxWidth: 200)
                } else {
                  Image(systemName: "heart")
                    .resizable()
                    .frame(width: 200)
                }
                Image(systemName: "play")
              }
              .onTapGesture {
                tappedVideoURL = url
              }
              .sheet(item: $tappedVideoURL) { newURL in
                let _ = print(newURL.path)
                let player: AVPlayer = .init(url: newURL)
                VideoPlayer(player: player)
                  .onAppear {
                    player.play()
                  }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
    .onChange(of: results) { newResults in
      Task {
        do {
          let newImages = try await loadPhotos(results: newResults)
          print(newImages.count)
          self.images = newImages
        } catch {
          print(error)
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```swift
struct PhotoPicker: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
  @Binding public var results: [PHPickerResult]
    
  init(results: Binding<[PHPickerResult]>) {
    self._results = results
  }
  
  func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> PHPickerViewController {
    var configuration = PHPickerConfiguration(photoLibrary: .shared())
    configuration.preselectedAssetIdentifiers = results.compactMap(\.assetIdentifier)
    configuration.selectionLimit = 0
    let picker = PHPickerViewController(configuration: configuration)
    picker.delegate = context.coordinator
    return picker
  }
  
  func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: PHPickerViewController, context: Context) {
  }
  
  func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
    return Coordinator(self)
  }
  
  class Coordinator: NSObject, PHPickerViewControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {
    var parent: PhotoPicker
    
    init(_ parent: PhotoPicker) {
      self.parent = parent
    }
    
    func picker(_ picker: PHPickerViewController, didFinishPicking results: [PHPickerResult]) {
      picker.dismiss(animated: true)
      parent.results = results
    }
  }
}
```

```swift
extension NSItemProvider {
  public func loadFileRepresentation(forTypeIdentifier typeIdentifier: String) async throws -> URL {
    try await withCheckedThrowingContinuation { continuation in
      self.loadFileRepresentation(forTypeIdentifier: typeIdentifier) { url, error in
        if let error = error {
          return continuation.resume(throwing: error)
        }
        
        guard let url = url else {
          return continuation.resume(throwing: NSError())
        }
        
        continuation.resume(returning: url)
      }.resume()
    }
  }
  
  public func loadObject(ofClass aClass : NSItemProviderReading.Type) async throws -> NSItemProviderReading {
    try await withCheckedThrowingContinuation { continuation in
      self.loadObject(ofClass: aClass) { data, error in
        if let error = error {
          return continuation.resume(throwing: error)
        }
        
        guard let data = data else {
          return continuation.resume(throwing: NSError())
        }
        
        continuation.resume(returning: data)
      }.resume()
    }
  }
}
```

```swift
struct LivePhoto: UIViewRepresentable {
    let livePhoto: PHLivePhoto
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> PHLivePhotoView {
        let livePhotoView = PHLivePhotoView()
        livePhotoView.livePhoto = livePhoto
        return livePhotoView
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ livePhotoView: PHLivePhotoView, context: Context) {
    }
}
```

```swift
extension URL: Identifiable {
  public var id: URL {
    return self
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`PHPickerConfiguration`の`preferredAssetRepresentationMode`を`current`にしたら取得できるようになりました。